# SQL Transpose 1 row in column and group the similar values

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i work on phpmyadmin and i don't have the command PIVOT. I just want a command for display a table like that

The origin table

| SIGMA | TARIF | VOL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 58 | T3 | 45 |
| 58 | T4 | 89 |
| 58 | T5 | 88 |
| 58 | T6 | 99 |
| 58 | T7 | 1 |
| 59 | T3 | 400 |
| 59 | T4 | 900 |

SIGMA AND TARIF ARE INDEXED like a primary key

I have like 197 differents TARIF and 40,000 SIGMA

I want display the table like that

| SIGMA | T3 | T4 | T5 | T6 | T7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58 | 45 | 89 | 88 | 99 | 1 |
| 59 | 400 | 500 | ETC | ETC | ETC |

Thanks you ;)

Comment: You can try to google something like "dynamic pivot for MySQL"

Comment: thanks u, i didnt know how it was called

Comment: @MartinMaxime check if it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succed....

`````
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when TARIF = ''',
      TARIF,
      ''' then VOL1AN end) ',
      TARIF
    )
  ) INTO @sql 
FROM
  direction_prix_volumes.volumes1an_tarif_proxi;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT SIGMA, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM direction_prix_volumes.volumes1an_tarif_proxi 
                   GROUP BY SIGMA');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;````
`````